# Access fold data generated from createFolds by fold ID not Name

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am creating 10 folds using createFolds in the caret library,
After creating the folds I want to access the data related to the Ids in each fold.

This line of code is working fine:

```
data[folds$Fold1,]
```

But when I access it by fold id, it gives an error:

```
data[folds[1],]
```

The error is: Error in `[.default`(xj, i) : invalid subscript type 'list'

Here is a complete sample code:

```
library(caret)
data=data.frame(V1=LETTERS)
folds <- createFolds(data[,1], k = 5, list = T, returnTrain = FALSE)
#this line is working fine
data[folds$Fold1,]
#this line gives error " invalid subscript type 'list' "
data[folds[1],]
```

Comment: Use `data[folds[[1]],]`

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks.